# How to transform to TAB delimited text file using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have already xslt code which usually transform the data to CSV text file with COMMA delimited but I would like to modify this code to transform the data into CSV with TAB DELIMITED FILE. Could you please help to alter this.

And also please guide me some materials to learn basics.
Thanks,
Deepa.

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync" xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xs ws" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xtt:quotes="csv" xtt:separator="
 ">
<xsl:for-each select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Worker/ws:Additional_Information">
<xsl:variable name="Current_date">
<xsl:value-of select="current-date()"/>
</xsl:variable>
<Record xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="csv">
<PositionName>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:PositionName"/>
</PositionName>
<EffectiveStartDate xtt:dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy">
<xsl:value-of select="$Current_date"/>
</EffectiveStartDate>
<EffectiveEndDate xtt:dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy">
<xsl:value-of select="ws:EffectiveEndDate"/>
</EffectiveEndDate>
<EmployeeID>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:EmployeeID"/>
</EmployeeID>
<PayeeType>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:PayeeType"/>
</PayeeType>
<PlanName>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</PlanName>
<ManagerName>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:ManagerName"/>
</ManagerName>
<TitleName>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:JobCode"/>
</TitleName>
<PositionGroupName>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</PositionGroupName>
<TargetCompensation>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</TargetCompensation>
<UnitTypeForTargetCompensation>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UnitTypeForTargetCompensation>
<BusinessUnitName>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:BusinessUnitName"/>
</BusinessUnitName>
<Description>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</Description>
<JobTitle>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:JobTitle"/>
</JobTitle>
<JobProfile>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:JobProfile"/>
</JobProfile>
<TeamNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</TeamNumber>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE4>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:Location"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE4>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE5>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:PlanNo"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE5>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE6>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE6>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE7>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE7>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE8>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE8>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE9>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE9>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE10>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE10>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE11>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE11>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE12>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE12>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE13>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE13>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE14>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE14>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE15>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE15>
<GENERICATTRIBUTE16>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICATTRIBUTE16>
<GENERICNUMBER1>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICNUMBER1>
<UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER1>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER1>
<GENERICNUMBER2>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICNUMBER2>
<UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER2>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER2>
<GENERICNUMBER3>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICNUMBER3>
<UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER3>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER3>
<GENERICNUMBER4>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICNUMBER4>
<UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER4>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER4>
<GENERICNUMBER5>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICNUMBER5>
<UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER5>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER5>
<GENERICNUMBER6>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICNUMBER6>
<UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER6>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</UNITTYPEFORGENERICNUMBER6>
<GENERICDATE1>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:JobEntryDate"/>
</GENERICDATE1>
<GENERICDATE2>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICDATE2>
<GENERICDATE3>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICDATE3>
<GENERICDATE4>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICDATE4>
<GENERICDATE5>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICDATE5>
<GENERICDATE6>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICDATE6>
<GENERICBOOLEAN1>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICBOOLEAN1>
<GENERICBOOLEAN2>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICBOOLEAN2>
<GENERICBOOLEAN3>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICBOOLEAN3>
<GENERICBOOLEAN4>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICBOOLEAN4>
<GENERICBOOLEAN5>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICBOOLEAN5>
<GENERICBOOLEAN6>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</GENERICBOOLEAN6>
<CREDITSTARTDATE>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</CREDITSTARTDATE>
<CREDITENDDATE>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</CREDITENDDATE>
<PROCESSINGSTARTDATE>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</PROCESSINGSTARTDATE>
<PROCESSINGENDDATE>
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
</PROCESSINGENDDATE>
</Record>
</xsl:for-each>
</File>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal sample to demonstrate the issue, if you have some XML input post a minimal sample of it, then a minimal sample of the XSLT together with the output you want and the one you get. As you don't seem to transform XML to plain text but rather to some other XML input format that you might postprocess later to get CSV you will need to explain as well which tool that is.

Comment: It might help to change `Record xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="csv"` to `Record xtt:separator="&#9;" xtt:quotes="csv"`.

Comment: It's only a guess, but what happens if you change `xtt:separator=","` to `xtt:separator="&#9;"`?

Comment: I think that's a case of "snap!" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(card_game)

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin& Michael. Its perfectly working fine.